# Files.isExecutable(...) giving false though i have permission to the file

Tags: java, jvm

I was using java.nio.file.Files class to check the login user has permission to execute file. Though i have permission to execute file (i.e i can run that file manually), isExecutable(pathToFile) returning false. does JVM don't have permission to execute the file?

Comment: That's exactly what you should deduce : The OS user has right to execute the file but not the JVM.

Comment: So. is there a way to grant permission to JVM?

Comment: See this - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Files.is…` convenience methods like `Files.isExecutable(path)` are good, if a simple `true`/`false` answer is sufficient, in which case they spare you from dealing with exception handling, but not much helpful when you want to know details. If you retrace what will happen in the background, you can `catch` the exception yourself to find out the reason why the JVM assumes that executing the file won’t work:

```
try {
    path.getFileSystem().provider().checkAccess(path, AccessMode.EXECUTE);
    System.out.println("can execute "+path);
} catch(IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("can not execute: "+ex);
}
```

The exception (or its actual type) might tell you about the reasons.

Note that this is an `IOException`. Contrary to the comments on your question, you can preclude a security policy issue. If there was a JVM security policy forbidding the access, the `SecurityException` was also be thrown when calling `Files.isExecutable(path)`, which you had noticed.

If `Files.isExecutable(path)` returns `false`, you can safely assume that an `IOException` has been thrown by `checkAccess`, either, because it was assumed that the current user indeed has not enough access rights or because there was an I/O issue before getting to consider the access rights.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it is throwing exception with cause. it turns out a [bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7190897)  in java 7 which was fixed in 8.